# Is this an extraposed subject?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar, extraposition

> 1. It is even possible I somehow sensed those qualities which I have since discovered to be so significantly a part of her.

Does the sentence above have an extraposed subject? If so, which of the following clauses would be the extraposed subject?

- I have since possibly discovered those qualities to be significantly a part of her.
- I somehow sensed those qualities which I have since possibly discovered to be significantly a part of her.

> 2. It is quite possible that we had a perfectly civil exchange before I began my retreat back to my own table.

Does example (2) above have an extraposed subject. If so, is the subject as follows:

- That we  had a perfect exchange before I began my retreat back to my own table is quite possible.

Comment: Is **what** an extraposed subject, exactly? I don’t understand the format of your question… what are you actually asking? There are definitely extraposed subjects in your sentences, yes.

Comment: sentence #1: I can say: it seems even possible I somehow sensed those qualities which I have since discovered to be significantly a part of her. which makes me think that ''even possible'' is extraposed at the beginning as a focus. But I can also add ''even possible'' in the middle of the sentence, which gave me the feeling that ''even possible'' could be in fact a cleavage in the sentence. PS: if it was an extraposed of the subject, I could not add ''even possible'' in the middle of the sentence but only at the end of the sentence.

Comment: I still don’t see what you’re trying to say. You can’t really add _even possible_ “in the middle of the sentence” (where exactly?). I mean, you could say “those even possible qualities”, but that would be bizarre. In your first bullet points, you replace the adjectival phrase _(even) possible_ with the adverbial _possibly_, which is just changing the structure completely, and quite orthogonal to extraposition. At any rate, _even possible_ is not extraposed as focus, because that’s not what extraposition does or how it works.

Comment: I will try again to explain my point of view: it, is a non-referential pronoun, it is just here to introduce a new information. In those extraposed-sentences, the informations which are known are in general place at the end of the sentence and the focus at the beginning of the sentence, introduce by the pronoun it.

Comment: Yes, that is true: the extraposed content comes at the _end_ (whether to give focus to what then ends up at the beginning or not). “Even possible” is not at the end, but at the beginning, so it is clearly not extraposed. The rephrasing you have done of sentence 2 correctly un-extraposes the subject (the long content clause), and the first sentence can be un-extraposed in the same way. So the answer to the question in the title is ***Yes***. What I don’t understand is what the two rewritings of sentence 1 are supposed to be for. What question do they relate to?

Comment: thanks for all your efforts, by the way, it is really helpful. If we both agree that number one has an extraposed of the subject. Can I place the constituant: ''possible'' at the end of the sentence, for example:  I somehow sensed those qualities which I have since discovered to be so significantly a part of her possible. (I think even is not required). PS: my goal is to reverse the sentence without it.

Comment: No, you can’t. You cannot “sense [something] possible” because _sense_ is not a linking verb. It can take an infinitival complement, though, which can be a linking verb; so you can say, “I sensed those qualities […] to be possible”. That is still a completely different sentence, though. In the original, what is possible is not the qualities, but the fact that the qualities were sensed by you: “That I somehow sensed those qualities […] is even possible”.

Comment: Does the sentence above have an extraposed subject? If so, which of the following cluases would be the extraposed subject?                                      here is my answer: I somehow sensed those qualities which I have since discovered to be so significantly a part of her.  Does example (2) above have an extraposed subject. If so, is the subject as follows:  YES :))  YOU DID IT! well done! it was simple, but somehow I could not figured it out by myself. Many thanks @YanusBahsJacquet :)